# UIDatePicker and date not storing properly

Tags: ios, nsdate, uidatepicker

I have an IBAction method tied to a UIToolbarButton that runs the following code.

The UIDatePicker is setup only to show the time to the user.
 Therefore, the picker randomly chooses the date: sometimes the date is today, sometimes the date is tomorrow. I want the picker to always choose the time selected (but always in the future). e.g. If the user picks 6:00AM at 10:00PM on Jan 1st, I want the date to store 6:00 AM on Jan 2nd.

The following if should do that, however 50% of the time NSLog returns one answer and 50% of the time it returns the other.

```
if (self.picker.date >= [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]) {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDate *pickerdate = self.picker.date;
    [defaults setObject:pickerdate forKey:@"pickerdate"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    NSLog(@"The date is more than now. Pickerdate is %@",pickerdate);
}
else {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSCalendar*       calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    components.day = 1;
    NSDate * pickerdate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents: components toDate: self.picker.date options: 0];
    [defaults setObject:pickerdate forKey:@"pickerdate"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    NSLog(@"The date is less than now. Pickerdate is %@",pickerdate);
}
```

EDIT: Code modified, my logic was backwards but the problem remains.

Comment: You can't use the `>=` (or similar) operator to compare two `NSDate` objects. These are objects. You must use the `compare:` method to compare the two dates. As you have it you are comparing to see if one object pointer is greater than or equal to another object pointer. Definitely not what you want.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I forgot about compare for NSDate objects. How could I find if one is greater than the other though?

Comment: Saw class reference for  isLaterThanOrEqualTo and  isEarlierThanOrEqualTo.

Comment: Try `if ([self.picker.date compare:[NSDate date]] != NSOrderDescending)`. That should be the same as `>=`. I may have that backwards. If that doesn't work correctly, change to `NSOrderedAscending`. BTW - `[NSDate date]` gives you "now".

Comment: Can you put that in as an answer with `if ([self.picker.date compare:[NSDate date]] != NSOrderedAscending)` so I can accept it? And THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `>=` (or similar) operator to compare two `NSDate` objects. These are objects. You must use the `compare:` method to compare the two dates. As you have it you are comparing to see if one object pointer is greater than or equal to another object pointer. Definitely not what you want.

The proper replacement would be:

```
if ([self.picker.date compare:[NSDate date]] != NSOrderAscending) {
```

Note that `[NSDate date]` gives the same result as `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]`.